# Prove that for any non constant entire function $\infty$ is an asymptotic value

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F$ be an entire function. We say that $a \in \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ is an asymptotic value for $F$ if there exists a continuous curve going from a finite point to infinity such that $F$ tends to $a$ along that curve. Prove that for any non constant entire function $\infty$ is an asymptotic value.

I encountered this problem in an old qualifying exam. My thoughts on this are that if we assume that $\infty$ is not an asymptotic value, then for every continuous curve from a finite  point to infinity $F$ tends to some finite value along that curve. One possibility is that $F$ tends to the same finite value in which case $F$ has a finite limit at $\infty$. Hence on the compact set $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$, $F$ is bounded. Then we reach the contradiction that $F$ is bounded by Liouville's theorem. The other possibility is that $F$ does not have a limit at $\infty$ but takes on finite values in the neighborhood of $\infty$. In this case, we are probably getting a contradiction from Picard's Great Theorem.

Can someone please comment on this argument and point out possible wrong inferences or missing details?

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong.  Whether $\infty$ is or is not an asymptotic value, you could have curves on which $F$ is unbounded without having a limit.

Comment: I see my mistake. Can you please point to the right approach? Should I try to construct a curve on which $\infty$ is an asymptotic value?

Comment: Or is it more sensible to consider the behavior of any entire function at infinity. Since the function cannot have a removable singularity there, hence it will have either a pole or an essential singularity. How do we proceed from here?

Comment: @ Robert Israel: Could you kindly base your statement?

Answer (score 2):

For example, see [A. S. B. Holland, Introduction to the theory of entire functions, pp. 159-160](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=uuwxMtZEgWwC&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=Is+the++infinity+an+asymptotic+value+of+entire+function?&source=bl&ots=-BcNLCZfiW&sig=VyL9NS7OhVEokGjmwzfbFVaNSqg&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=5UXfU-qbCs6P4gTuyoGAAg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=Is%20the%20%20infinity%20an%20asymptotic%20value%20of%20entire%20function%3F&f=false) for the proof.